# Dynamically Creating Variables In Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, dynamic, variables

i'm loading several sound files, and want to error check each load.  however, instead programming each one with their own complete/error functions, i would like them to all use the same complete/error handler functions.

a successfully loaded sound should create a new sound channel variable, while an unsuccessfully loaded sound will produce a simple trace with the name of the sound that failed to load.  however, in order to do this, i need to dynamically create variables, which i haven't yet figured out how to do.

here's my code for my complete and error functions:

```
function soundLoadedOK(e:Event):void
 {
 //EX: Sound named "explosion" will create Sound Channel named "explosionChannel"
 var String(e.currentTarget.name + "Channel"):SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
 }

function soundLoadFailed(e:IOErrorEvent):void
 {
 trace("Failed To Load Sound:" + e.currentTarget.name);
 }
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
UPDATED (RE: viatropos)
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

can not find the error.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access    a property or method of a null object    reference. at    lesson12_start_fla::MainTimeline/loadSounds() at    lesson12_start_fla::MainTimeline/frame1():

```
//Sounds
var soundByName:Object = {};
var channelByName:Object = {};
var soundName:String;
var channelName:String;
loadSounds();

function loadSounds():void
{
    var files:Array = ["robotArm.mp3", "click.mp3"];
    var i:int = 0;
    var n:int = files.length;
    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        soundName = files[i];
        soundByName[soundName] = new Sound();
        soundByName[soundName].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sound_completeHandler);
        soundByName[soundName].addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sound_ioErrorHandler);
        soundByName[soundName].load(new URLRequest(soundName));
    }
}

function sound_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    channelName = event.currentTarget.id3.songName;
    channelByName[channelName] = new SoundChannel();
}

function sound_ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Failed To Load Sound:" + event.currentTarget.name);
}
```

Comment: You could add your new channel into an array( channels.push(new SoundChannel()), or into a Dictionary. It would help to have sound channels easy to reference by name for example. Also you might want to have a look at the SoundManager.as class on Matt Przybylski's blog ( http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/07/15/as3/as3-soundmanager/ ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a few ways:

1. Storing your SoundChannels in an Array.  Good if you care about order or you don't care about getting them by name.
2. Storing SoundChannels by any name in an `Object`.  Good if you want to easily be able to get the by name.  Note, the `Object` class can only store keys (`{key:value}` or `object[key] = value`) that are Strings.  If you need Objects as keys, use `flash.utils.Dictionary`, it's a glorified hash.

Here's an example demonstrating using an Array vs. an Object.

```
var channels:Array = [];
// instead of creating a ton of properties like
// propA propB propC
// just create one property and have it keep those values
var channelsByName:Object = {};

function loadSounds():void
{
    var files:Array = ["soundA.mp3", "soundB.mp3", "soundC.mp3"];
    var sound:Sound;
    var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
    var i:int = 0;
    var n:int = files.length;
    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        sound = new Sound();
        sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sound_completeHandler);
        sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sound_ioErrorHandler);
        sound.load(files[i]);
    }
}

function sound_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // option A
    var channelName:String = event.currentTarget.id3.songName;
    // if you want to be able to get them by name
    channelsByName[channelName] = new SoundChannel();

    // optionB
    // if you just need to keep track of all of them,
    // and don't care about the name specifically
    channels.push(new SoundChannel())
}

function sound_ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Failed To Load Sound:" + event.currentTarget.name);
}
```

Let me know if that works out.

Comment: sure.  but my problem as far as i can see is that while i can iterate thru an array of sounds, sending them all one by one to get complete/error checked, i need to create individual Sound Channel variables for each sound if it has loaded successfully.

Comment: thanks.  i see what you are instructing.  although i'm still having a error which i can not solve.  in order to play a sound, i also need to create a soundByName:Object along with channelByName:Object that stops a sound.  i've updated my original post with my new code

Comment: i'm still not understanding what's wrong with my updated code.

Comment: I updated my code and your code up top, we just needed to instantiate the hashes: channelsByName:Object = {}.

Comment: new problem:
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property name not found on flash.media.Sound and there is no default value.
 at lesson12_start_fla::MainTimeline/sound_completeHandler()

Comment: i've started a new thread for this new problem since it has left the scope of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395226/actionscript-loading-calling-sounds-from-string-array

Comment: it looks like there is no 'name' property on the sound object: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html.  Sound does have these two properties: 'url', and 'id3'.  I've never used Sound before, but I recommend getting the name via `event.currentTarget.id3.songName': http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/ID3Info.html. Updated our answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load Sounds
var soundDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var soundByName:Object = new Object();
var channelByName:Object = new Object();

loadSounds();

function loadSounds():void
    {
    var files:Array = ["robotArm.mp3", "click.mp3"]; //etc.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
        var soundName:String = files[i];
        var sound:Sound=new Sound(); 
        soundDictionary[sound] = soundName;
        soundByName[soundName] = sound;
        sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sound_completeHandler);
        sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sound_ioErrorHandler); 
        sound.load(new URLRequest(soundName));
        }
    }                                                                        

function sound_completeHandler(e:Event):void
    {
    var soundName:String=soundDictionary[e.currentTarget];                      
    channelByName[soundName] = new SoundChannel();                          
    }

function sound_ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
    trace("Failed To Load Sound:" + soundDictionary[e.currentTarget]);
    }

//Play Sound
channelByName["robotArm.mp3"] = soundByName["robotArm.mp3"].play();

//Stop Sound
channelByName["robotArm.mp3"].stop();
```