# Actionscript Loading/Calling Sounds From String Array

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, object, audio

i'm attempting to instantiate a bunch of sounds by creating a string array containing each sound's filepath (or name).

```
var soundByName:Object = {};
var channelByName:Object = {};
var soundName:String;
var channelName:String;
loadSounds();

function loadSounds():void
    {
    var files:Array = new Array("sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3"); //etc.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
        soundName = files[i];
        soundByName.soundName = new Sound();
        soundByName.soundName.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sound_completeHandler);
        soundByName.soundName.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sound_ioErrorHandler);
        soundByName.soundName.load(new URLRequest(soundName));
        }
    }

function sound_completeHandler(e:Event):void
    {
    channelName = e.currentTarget.name;
    channelByName.channelName = new SoundChannel();
    }

function sound_ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
    trace("Failed To Load Sound:" + e.currentTarget.name);
    }
```

then called like this:

```
//Stop a sound
channelByName["sound1.mp3"].stop();

//Play a sound
channelByName["sound2.mp3"] = soundByName["sound2.mp3"].play();
```

my current code contains an error from the sound_completeHandler() function stating that the 'name' property wasn't found.  i can't figure out how to add this name property, or how else to reference the e.currentTarget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong in 3 parts:

- soundByName is an Object and you are doing a `soundByName.soundName=new Sound()` => you are creating a field named soundName within soundByName.
  Use `soundByName[soundName]=new Sound();` which mean create a field with the name taken from the variable coundName.
- You are doing the same with channelByName use `channelByName[channelName]=value;`
- Then you want to associate a `soundChannel` from your name, it can't work `Sound` object have no such field. Use a dictionary where you will associating the sound with  the name.

  ```
  var nameBySound:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
  var soundByName:Object = {};
  var channelByName:Object = {};
  loadSounds();

  function loadSounds():void {
    var files:Array = ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3"]; //etc.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     var soundName:String = files[i];
     var sound:Sound=new Sound(); 
     nameBySound[sound] = soundName;
     soundByName[soundName] = sound;
     sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sound_completeHandler);
     sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sound_ioErrorHandler); 
     sound.load(new URLRequest(soundName));
    }
  }                                                                        

  function sound_completeHandler(e:Event):void {                           
   var soundName:String=nameBySound[e.currentTarget];                      
   channelByName[soundName] = new SoundChannel();                          
  }                                                                        

  function sound_ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
   trace("Failed To Load Sound:" + nameBySound[e.currentTarget]);
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks.  this works well.  i've been meaning to read about the dictionary class.  in your opinion, do you think this approach of mine is the good way for loading / calling many sounds?

Comment: Well you can for example use only one dictionary to put all the infos into (name, sound, soundchannel). It depends also of your usage of the code.